# Composer.json require a linux command

Tags: php, linux, shell, composer-php

I have a package that uses the `rsync` command (i.e. by calling it using `exec()`).  I'd like to add this as a required dependency in my `composer.json` file.  Anyone know if this is possible?  I didn't really think this would work, and it didn't, but I tried:

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.3.0",
  "rsync": ">=2.6.0"
}
```

EDIT:  I don't need composer to actually install the command.  I just want some kind of dependency enforcement--so the user will know early on that the package won't work.

What I ended up doing is just throwing an exception if the package is used without rsync available.